# Change telegram desktop messages font family

Tags: kde, fonts, manjaro

I installed Manjaro with KDE and installed the Telegram desktop app.

The Telegram desktop messages in persian font are very ugly. Is there any way to change the font family?

Comment: This question already has an [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087439/telegram-persian-font-changed-after-upgrade-to-18-10/1118690#comment1958908_1118690).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered in [Properly update Telegram](https://askubuntu.com/a/954168).

Just delete this version you've downloaded from their website, and install telegram like this:

```
sudo apt-get install telegram-desktop
```

This worked for me.